# Improving identicon graphics

Tags: graphics

This question has two parts, a technical part about graphics, and a creative part. I'll accept answers primarily re the first part.

The application is to come up with graphical identicons to distinguish data layers. The approach is to leverage the file system and simply tokenize the paths.

This function takes file paths (as generated by say `FileNames`) as input, tokenize them, and use the prefix of a hash code (eg MD5 here) to color the path components.

Using the handy position-coded curry "bullet" operator:

```
\[Bullet] /: f_[pre___, \[Bullet] , post___] := 
  With[{n = Length[List@pre], m = Length[List@post]} ,
    Curry[f, Join[Range[n], {n + m + 1}, Range[m] + n]][pre, post] ];
```

The identicon generator becomes:

```
pathFlagIdenticon[h_] :=      
  Query[StringSplit[\[Bullet], "/"]] /* 
   Query[All, 
    Hash[\[Bullet], "MD5"] /* IntegerDigits[\[Bullet], 8, 36] /* 
     Query[1 ;; 3 h] /* 
     BlockMap[
      Query[{Total /* OddQ , (#/7 &) /* Apply[RGBColor]} /* 
        Replace[{{True, rgb_} :> rgb, {False, rgb_} :> 
           White}]], \[Bullet], 3]] /* Image /* 
   ImageRotate[\[Bullet], Pi/2] /* 
   Show[\[Bullet], ImageSize -> {60, 30}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, All},
     AspectRatio -> 1/3];
```

The graphics generated by each path component is a vertical column (currently only using a fraction of the hash string) and multiple path components are arranged horizontally - hence "pathFlag", so all files with the same path prefix share the same vertical stripes starting at left.

This works ok eg, given files:

```
{".DS_Store", 
"Readme.gdoc", 
"SUBMISSION/Data/Dictionaries/.DS_Store", "SUBMISSION/Data/Dictionaries/heloc_data_dictionary-2-Original.xlsx",
"SUBMISSION/Data/Dictionaries/heloc_data_dictionary-2.tsv",
"SUBMISSION/Data/Dictionaries/helocDataDictionary-Original.gsheet",
"SUBMISSION/Data/Dictionaries/helocDataDictionary.tsv",
"SUBMISSION/Data/Dictionaries/MaxDelq.gsheet",
"SUBMISSION/Data/.DS_Store"\
...}
```

Gives:

```
Dataset[files ][All, 
   StringDrop[\[Bullet], StringLength[path]] /* {pathFlagIdenticon[4],
      Identity}] // Normal // Column
```

(figure shows just a portion)

[image]

However, attempting to improve the graphics to include not just colored squares but also other shapes, eg circles,

```
graphicsRules = With[{z = 1, au = Automatic},
   {
    {{n_ /; Mod[n, 3] == 0, rgb_}, pos_} :> 
     Inset[Graphics@{rgb, Disk[]}, pos, {0, 0}, z],
    {{n_ /; Mod[n, 3] == 1, rgb_}, pos_} :> 
     Inset[Graphics@{rgb, Rectangle[]}, pos, {0, 0}, z],
    {{n_ /; Mod[n, 3] == 2, rgb_}, pos_} :> 
     Inset[Graphics@{White, Rectangle[]}, pos, {0, 0}, z]
    }
   ];
```

Run into problems with `Inset`. So first, what are the appropriate `Inset` options to render each cell contained in a unit square?

```
pathFlagWithShapes[h_] :=
  Query[StringSplit[\[Bullet], "/"]] /* 
   Query[All, 
    Hash[\[Bullet], "MD5"] /* IntegerDigits[\[Bullet], 8, 36] /* 
     Query[1 ;; 3 h] /* 
     BlockMap[Query[{Total , (#/7 &) /* Apply[RGBColor]} ], \[Bullet],
       3]] /* MapIndexed[
    List /* Replace[graphicsRules], \[Bullet], {2}] /* Graphics /*  
   ImageRotate[\[Bullet], 0*Pi/2] /* 
   Show[\[Bullet], ImageSize -> 7 {30, 30}, PlotRange -> {All, All}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/1, Frame -> True];
```

The output is not as intended:

```
Dataset[files ][All, 
   StringDrop[\[Bullet], 
     StringLength[path]] /* {pathFlagWithShapes[4], Identity}] // 
  Normal // Column
```

[image]

Why are the graphics ranges going to ~200 when each is being indexMapped to no more than ~10 path components and each graphics element is supposed to be unit size?

That's the technical graphics question.

In addition to circles, would like to add triangle of various orientations, Harvey balls (disks that span not 2Pi angle but some multiple of Pi/2).

The creative part is, perhaps there are other graphical elements that would make the various paths even more distinguishable?

Comment: You might want to include your definition of \\[Bullet].

Comment: @CarlWoll, thanks forgot that, just added.

Answer (score 3):

In what follows I'll present a possible solution to the problem in the question. I will not report on alternative graphical elements, but I will present an implementation that can have the following effect on a list of paths (these are simulated data, not the ones provided in the question-the discussion below uses original data from the question)

[image: [insert preview.tiff]]

- ### "Why it doesn't work as expected?"

I'm not sure what's expected, but I can understand how the output seems *out of whack*. I think the most probable culprit is the definition of `graphicsRule`; in particular, the undesirable visual result is probably related to the parameters supplied to `Inset` therein.

**Let's look at an example:**

I will define a stripped down form of `pathFlagWithShapes` where everything after `Graphics` (ie `ImageRotate` etc) is removed (I won't include the code here to avoid clutter). Evaluating this reduced form of `pathFlagWithShapes` on the supplied `files` returns something like the following excerpts (again, won't include all the output for obvious reasons):

[image: [insert 11.png]]

(these are the second and third entries of the output, presented side-by-side)

The first impression is that the `Disk`'s are *somehow* off center; also, there seems to be an *awful lot* of white space. To investigate, we'll redefine `graphicsRule` (this time, using `SetDelayed` because otherwise the `Graphics` primitives complain-its suppressed by the semicolon used in the original code) so as to make all `White` `Rectangle`'s, `Orange` to enhance visibility. (A portion of) the results are presented below:

[image: [insert 21.png]]

Seeing all this orange color suggests that the relative positions of the circles and the rectangles are incompatible. To remedy that, we'll edit the previous definition of `graphicsRules`, namely we'll replace `Inset[Graphics@{rgb, Disk[]}, pos, {0, 0}, z]` with `Inset[Graphics@{rgb, Disk[]}, pos, {-1, -1}, z]`. Evaluating once more returns:

[image: [insert 31.png]]

(again, these are the second and third entries of the output from evaluation when using the restricted form of `pathFlagWithShapes`)

Finally, we'll augment the definition of  `Graphics` in `pathFlagWithShapes` (see above) with

```
Graphics[\[Bullet], PlotRange -> {{1, Automatic}, {1, 5}}, ImageSize -> Tiny]
```

and obtain

[image: [insert 41.png]]

The code used so far reads

```
(*  wasn't sure what to use for path *)
With[{path = "C:\\", h = 4}, 
  Dataset[files][All, StringDrop[\[Bullet], StringLength[path]] /*
    {pathFlagWithShapes[h], Identity}] // Normal // Column
 ]

(* short version with augmented Graphics *)
pathFlagWithShapes[h_] := Query[StringSplit[\[Bullet], "/"]] /* 
  Query[All, Hash[\[Bullet], "MD5"] /* IntegerDigits[\[Bullet], 8, 36] /* 
    Query[1 ;; 3 h] /* 
      BlockMap[Query[{Total, (#/7 &) /* Apply[RGBColor]}], \[Bullet], 3]] /*     
        MapIndexed[List /* Replace[graphicsRules], \[Bullet], {2}] /*
          Graphics[\[Bullet], PlotRange -> {{1, Automatic}, {1, 5}}, ImageSize -> Tiny
 ]

(* changed Set to SetDelayed, colors and third argument of Inset for Circle's *)
graphicsRules := With[{z = 1, au = Automatic}, 
  {{{n_ /; Mod[n, 3] == 0, rgb_}, pos_} :> Inset[Graphics@{rgb, Disk[]}, pos, {-1, -1}, z], 
  {{n_ /; Mod[n, 3] == 1, rgb_}, pos_} :> Inset[Graphics@{rgb, Rectangle[]}, pos, {0, 0}, z], 
  {{n_ /; Mod[n, 3] == 2, rgb_}, pos_} :> Inset[Graphics@{Orange, Rectangle[]}, pos, {0, 0}, z]}
 ]
```

---

- ### "Do you have a better idea?"

I'm glad you asked; sure, I have a thought or two.

All jokes aside, I don't think that what I'll present below is necessarily *better* and I also have a persistent feeling that it definitely is *not* as efficient as it could have been (there's a lot of `Map`'s, for one thing); I just got excited with the `\[Bullet]` and figured I should give it a go. Just to give a hint of what I tried, in the following I'll present only output with `Rectangle`'s and `Circles` because I didn't like how `Triangle`'s and `Parallelogram`'s looked, but they worked too so anyone interested can try them out for themselves.

**The `palette`**

This is the `palette`. We'll be using it to provide (reproducible and random) custom color for our shapes.

```
With[{f = Rescale /* Mean, keys = {"Index", "Gradient", "Function"}, seed = RandomInteger[{10^5, 10^6}]},
  palette[nGradients_, seeding_: seed] := Module[{grads, fAssembleRow, dts, fSel},
    BlockRandom[grads = RandomChoice[ColorData["Gradients"], nGradients],    RandomSeeding -> seeding];
    fAssembleRow = Join[#2, {#1, f /* ColorData[#1, "ColorFunction"]}] &;
    dts = MapIndexed[AssociationThread[keys -> fAssembleRow[##]] &, grads] // Dataset;
    fSel[jSelect_] = Query[Select[#Index == jSelect &], "Function"] /* Normal /* First;
    <|"Data" -> dts, "Selector" -> (fSel[#] &), "Seed" -> seed|>
   ]
 ]
```

`colorize` is the interface to out `palette`:

```
colorize[palette_, iSelect_] := palette["Data"] // palette["Selector"][iSelect]
```

For example, `pal = palette[3, 123456789]` is equipped with three random `"Gradients"` `"ColorFunction"`'s from `ColorData` and evaluates to:

[image: [insert 5.png]]

Also, `fCol = pal // colorize[\[Bullet], 1];` retrieves the first `"Gradient"` `"ColorFunction"` and stores it in `fCol`;  the following example uses a randomly generated $3 \times 3$ real matrix to display how `colorize` is used to paint three `Disks`'s.

```
BlockRandom[RandomReal[{0, 10}, {3, 3}], RandomSeeding -> 123654789] //
  Map[fCol[\[Bullet]] /* {\[Bullet], Disk[]} /* Graphics] // Row
```

> [image: [Insert 6.png]]

**The main `Dataset`** (*that will be used throughout*)

I find it useful to work with `Dataset`'s that have column headers. In what follows, `dts` will be transformed with various operations in order to obtain the desired result.

```
dts = files // Map[("full" -> \[Bullet]) /* Association] /* Dataset;
```

**The rest of the code**

```
encode[hash_][base_, len_] = Map[Hash[\[Bullet], hash] /* IntegerDigits[\[Bullet], base, len]];

With[{paltt = palette[2, 123654987]},
  post[take_][tuples_][j_] := Map[Take[\[Bullet], take] /* 
    BlockMap[(paltt // colorize[\[Bullet], j]), \[Bullet], tuples]]
 ];

postproc[hash_][base_, len_][take_][tuples_][j_] := StringSplit[\[Bullet], "\\" | "."] /* 
  encode[hash][base, len] /* post[take][tuples][j];

preproc[td_] := <|"path" -> (FileNameDrop[#full, td] &), 
 "name" -> (FileNameTake[#full, td] &), "full" -> (#full &)|>;

shapes = {Rectangle[], Disk[]};

assortment[n_] := ap[{\[Bullet], RandomChoice[shapes, n]} /* Transpose /* 
  Map[Graphics] /* Column /* Rasterize]

queryNames[hash_][base_, len_][take_][tuples_][j_] := 
  Query[GroupBy["path"], KeyDrop["path"], {"name" -> 
    postproc[hash][base, len][take][tuples][j] /* assortment[4]}];

consolidate[hash_][base_, len_][take_][tuples_][j_] := Function[{path, list}, 
  Map[Join[<|"path" -> (path // postproc[hash][base, len][take][tuples][j] //             
    assortment[4])|>, \[Bullet]], list]];

queryPaths[hash_][base_, len_][take_][tuples_][j_] := Query[
  KeyValueMap[consolidate[hash][base, len][take][tuples][j] /* Apply[Sequence]]];

iconize = ImageRotate[\[Bullet], Pi/2] /* 
  Show[\[Bullet], ImageSize -> {70, 30}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, All},  AspectRatio -> 1/3];

join = <|"idicon" -> (ImageCollage[Join[#path, #name], Method -> "Rows", 
  ImageSize -> {60, 30}] &), "full" -> (#full &)|>;
```

**The output**

Using the `files` provided in the question, we obtain:

```
dts // Query[All, preproc[-1]] /* queryNames["MD5"][8, 36][12][3][2] /*
  queryPaths["MD5"][8, 36][12][3][1] /* Query[All, join]
```

> [image: [insert 7.png]]

Comment: thanks for taking this up - but I don't think either your efforts or mine so far as usable for intended purpose: to pre-attentively distinguish and identify layers. - All the identicons look very similar. I think would have to add some symmetry (as per the original identicons) and/or modulate complexity of each level depend on how many elements exist at that level (since this is reflecting a filesystem tree)

Comment: thanks for the opportunity to work on it; the possibility of using a visual description for paths has been brewing at the back of my head for some time now but had never actually gotten any code written; I really enjoyed the `\[Bullet]`; it was a very ingenious solution to a very common problem